# Custom Alexa skill in lambda call/activate Devices in the Smart Home at a set time?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create an Alexa skill so I can say "Alexa, Turn the lights on at 5am for 3 hours" and Alexa will switch on my light device (lightwaverf device connected via the lightwaveRF home skill) at that time for that long.

I'm very new to Alexa development, and have created a couple of the basic tutorial skills in AWS lambda. What I'd like to know how to do is:

1) access the Smart Home devices in my account from my custom skill (ie is there a way to just send Alexa a string sentence ie - "Alexa switch on the kitchen light")

2) how to schedule this - ie can I use setTimeout() or setInterval etc to keep running in then background in lambda to then switch the lights on at the right time.

At the moment the skill I have created a custom skill that accepts the time and duration, as the Home Skills don;t give you this control over the dialogue.

Many thanks in advance for any help / input at all,

Answer (score 0):

Smart Home skills do not give you any control over what the user can say. It can only specify the device name and type.

To specify what the user can say requires a custom skill, and the user to invoke it with the skill's invocation phrase (skill name).

I don't think it is possible for a custom skill to talk directly to a smart home skill. However, I created a smart home skill and a custom skill that both use the same data stored on the device. This allows the custom skill to specify and update parameters used by the smart home skill. So it is possible to have a custom skill communicate with a smart home skill indirectly. Data could also be stored and shared via dynamoDB, for example.

Comment: Thanks for this Ron. It's a shame a custom skill can't interface with Alexa in general via natural language. When you create a Smart Home Skills I guess you have to write your own interface and integration to the devices? OR is there away in the Smart Skill to access already integrated providers via existing 3rd part Home Skills? Thanks again